# Modify the strategy importing module by hacking the sys.modules

Tags: python, python-module

As I read [`the question`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19540482/choose-adapter-dynamically-depending-on-libraries-installed). I came up with an idea. But I don't know the consequences of my **guesswork**.

My idea is that change the `import strategy` by modify the `sys.modules`, then change the import things without modify old code.

**Edit 1**

A situation use the method

**Hack code**:

```
try:
    import concurrent.futures
except ImportError:
    concurrent.futures = wrapper_futures
```

Then this code can use for python2 and python3

**Old code**:

```
from concurrent.futures import Future
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 try:
     from servicelibrary.simple import synchronous
 except ImportError:
     from servicelibrary.simple import alternative as synchronous
```

is probably a better way to do it if I understand your question properly

Comment: If my old code is in other files and I don't want to modify so many old code. Do you have a better way?

Comment: the biggest problem with your code is that its not very clear from reading it what it is doing ... just think if you need to go back and modify it in a year will you understand it? will someone else working on the project be able to understand what you are doing?